# I cannot print the 2nd field of matrix

Tags: r

If I input a row to x1000

```
> x1000 <- c(date=20140819, price=46.15)
> x1000
       date       price
20140819.00       46.15
```

I can print date and price.

```
> x1000[1]
    date
20140819

> x1000[2]
price
46.15
```

but if I add row into x1000 by the following code:

```
> x1000 <- rbind(x1000,c(20140820,46))
> x1000
          date price
x1000 20140819 46.15
      20140820 46.00
```

I cannot print the price 46.15 and 46.00

```
> x1000[1]
[1] 20140819

> x1000[2]
[1] 20140820

> x1000[[1]][1]
[1] 20140819

> x1000[[2]][1]
[1] 20140820

> x1000[[1]][2]
[1] NA

> x1000[[2]][2]
[1] NA
```

Why the values is NA? 
How can I print the price 46.15 and 46.00??

Could any expert can teach me? I am new to R language.

Comment: You transformed your data from one dimensional (vector) to a two dimensional (matrix), hence the indexing became two dimensional too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to print `price` just use either `x1000[, "price"]` or `x1000[, 2]`, also read about extracting elements from a matrix/data.frame, [see `?"["`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)